# Tricks for removing floating point rounding error?

Tags: java, rounding

First, let me start off by saying that I know there is no way to avoid rounding errors. My question rather lies in how to take rounding errors and fix them. "Why does it matter?", you may ask. In a java project of mine I have used the Separating Axis Theorem to implement collision detection/resolution for moving objects, and it works spectacularly well, but there is a flaw that I keep running into...

Rounding errors

I've made a picture to help illustrate what I'm talking about:
[image: SAT Collision Resolution]

Above is how I do collision resolution in my java project. Let me show how rounding errors can be problematic in this situation.

```
SV = MV.scale(2f(distance)/3f(move length))
```

2f/3f = 0.666666667 (approximately what will be displayed if you print 2/3)
0.666666667 is very bad because it actually causes the scale to be too large
0.000000001 scale too large, which means SV will be larger than expected, causing it to barely clip into the other shape upon collision resolution. Yes this is so very small that it cant be detected by a human, but it does indeed cause clipping, however small it may be, and as such I consider it a FAILED collision resolution.

My working solution thus far has been something like such

```
MV.scale((int)(2f/3f)*10000f)/10000f)
```

While this will probably work for all applications I would use my algorithm for, the loss in precision and probable eventual breaking at high numbers (because of the precision loss encountered there due to the nature of floating point numbers) make it hard to accept. I wouldn't have an issue with choosing 0.666666665 (or something close to it) through an algorithm, but I can't find an algorithm for finding the next closest floating point number to a number (and if it exists I'd be wary of performance drain).

Any ideas or alternate strategies? I'm kinda at my wits end here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use type `BigDecimal` instead of `Float` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler Implementing time-critical stuff with `BigDecimal` is a no-go (and actually *using* it in practice is far more complicated than one might expect, considering how nonchalantly people throw it in here in comments whenever someone asks *anything* about rounding errors). I think there are two options here: Conservatively subtract some epsilon from the "allowed movement distance", or try to cope with (i.e. resolve) an epsilon-sized *intersection* of the objects. There will likely be no practical way around this anyhow.

Comment: @Marco13 it certainly is kind of trade-off in between precision and performance. subtraction `0.000000001` per default would be an option, which would lead to a collision sooner - which is still just the same, but the other way around (because it is difficult to detect the cases where it has to be applied).